# Read Input File and Count in COBOL using Condition Names and Set

Tags: input, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, cobol

[This is the Assignment Outline in detail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II6Ft.png) ||
[This is what the input file looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D30NB.png)
Below is what I have.
[This is the Output I keep getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO8js.png) I can't figure out if it's not reading the file at all or not counting it. I've gone over every bit repeatedly and come up with nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  *This program will take in a file containing the roster of a
  *children's band and will generate an output report of the 
  *number of children playing an instrument from each category.

   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. LAB3A.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT BAND-FILE
           ASSIGN TO 'lab3-in.dat'
           ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
           ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD BAND-FILE.
   01 CHILD.
       05 NAME PIC X(12).
       05 GENDER PIC A.
       05 INST PIC X(15).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 ENDOFFILEINDICATOR PIC X.
      88 EOF VALUE 'Y' WHEN SET TO FALSE IS 'N'.
   01 CAT PIC X(15).
   01 BRASSCOUNT PIC 999.
   01 PERCCOUNT PIC 999.
   01 STRINGCOUNT PIC 999.
   01 WOODCOUNT PIC 999.
   01 OTHERCOUNT PIC 999.
   01 INSTRUMENT PIC X(15).
       88 BRASS VALUE 'Bugle' 'Flugelhorn' 'Sousaphone'
               'Trombone' 'Trumpet' 'Tuba'.
       88 PERC VALUE 'Bass Drum' 'Bells' 'Bongos' 'Castanets'
               'Chimes' 'Cymbals' 'Snare Drum' 'Xylophone'.
       88 STRINGS VALUE 'Banjo' 'Bass' 'Cello' 'Guitar' 'Harp'
               'Lyre' 'Mandolin' 'Violin'.
       88 WOOD VALUE 'Bagpipes' 'Bassoon' 'Clarinet' 'Flute'
               'Oboe' 'Piccolo' 'Saxophone'.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   000-MAIN.

       OPEN INPUT BAND-FILE
       PERFORM READ-BAND UNTIL NOT EOF
       PERFORM USEROUT
       CLOSE BAND-FILE
       STOP RUN.

   READ-BAND.
       READ BAND-FILE
          AT END
             SET EOF TO FALSE
          NOT AT END
             MOVE INST TO INSTRUMENT
             PERFORM CHECK-INST
       END-READ.

   CHECK-INST.
       IF BRASS
           ADD 1 TO BRASSCOUNT
           END-ADD
       END-IF
       IF PERC
           ADD 1 TO PERCCOUNT
           END-ADD
       END-IF 
       IF STRINGS
           ADD 1 TO STRINGCOUNT
           END-ADD
       END-IF
       IF WOOD
           ADD 1 TO WOODCOUNT
           END-ADD
       ELSE
           ADD 1 TO OTHERCOUNT
           END-ADD
       END-IF.

   USEROUT.
       DISPLAY ' '
       MOVE 'Brass:' TO CAT
       DISPLAY CAT BRASSCOUNT
       MOVE 'Percussion:' TO CAT
       DISPLAY CAT PERCCOUNT
       MOVE 'String:' TO CAT
       DISPLAY CAT STRINGCOUNT
       MOVE 'Woodwind:' TO CAT
       DISPLAY CAT WOODCOUNT
       MOVE 'Other:' TO CAT
       DISPLAY CAT OTHERCOUNT
       DISPLAY ' '.
```

Comment: put some `display` statements at various points in the program. That should tell you what is happening

Comment: You might try initializing the EOF variable and changing `UNTIL NOT EOF` till `UNTIL EOF`

Comment: I appreciate your help and the comment. I put displays in the NOT AT END indentation and got no output, so its not even going into that condition which narrows my problem down to the reading of the file.

Comment: Your input file doesn't look `SEQUENTIAL` but `LINE SEQUENTIAL`. If you aren't sure how your program works you may could use compiler-specific help: compile with `cobc -x -ftrace-all lab3.cob` and run with `COB_SET_TRACE=Y COB_TRACE_FILE=trace.log ./lab3` and inspect your program flow.
And... I'd suggest to switch to at least GnuCOBOL 2.2...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
 PERFORM READ-BAND UNTIL NOT EOF
```

to

```
 PERFORM READ-BAND UNTIL EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following changes to your code.

Please note that Statements delimited by ** means that I've changed your code.

In the Working Storage Section.

```
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  01 ENDOFFILEINDICATOR PIC X.
     **88 EOF VALUE 'Y'.**
```

In the Procedure Division.

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-MAIN.

   OPEN INPUT BAND-FILE
   PERFORM READ-BAND **UNTIL EOF**
   PERFORM USEROUT
   CLOSE BAND-FILE
   STOP RUN.
```

In the READ-BAND para.

```
READ-BAND.
   READ BAND-FILE
      AT END
         **SET EOF TO TRUE**
      NOT AT END
         MOVE INST TO INSTRUMENT
         PERFORM CHECK-INST
   END-READ.
```

With these changes in the code & by using the following input records,

```
Abby        FClarinet  
Amber       FFlute     
Amy         FBells     
Amy Farrah  FHarp      
Andrew      MSaxophone 
Arielle     MCastanets 
Brooke      MClarinet  
Colleen     FFlute     
Dana        FClarinet
```

I was able to obtain the following results,

```
Brass:            
Percussion:    002
String:        001
Woodwind:      006
Other:         003
```